# virtualbox refuse to run gnome on i7 computer

Tags: windows-7, gnome

Why does my virtualbox on i7 computer, refuse to run gnome? On my other notebook there is no problem, but with i7 I cannot run gnome. I get this error:

> opps, something went wrong

I already tried with fedora live and archlinux.

Comment: Well, with all of the troubleshooting steps you have detailed, it is hard to why you are having the issue.... Please tell us more about what you have done / tried and research you might have done. That error is a VB error but thats all we really know

Answer (score 1):

You must enable CPU virtualization in your bios before it will work. I fought the same problem with my i7 and virtual box....